# Facebook Graph Api: get all posts from page created by me

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I managing many pages for clients.

In each page there are several managers.

So i want to get from each page all the posts that created by me only.

How can i make this work?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/PAGE_ID/posts?access_tkoen=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

this will give me all the posts from all admins

Comment: no one have to get his own posts?

Comment: Using Graph API there is no way to filter posts of a page by the specific admin who created them. This is logic that you will have to create in your application - mapping the posts ids created through your application against the user who created them.